Is there a non-Map way to leave the Perpetual Mechanical Array boss chamber before unflooding the Aruami Ruins?
I encountered the Perpetual Mechanical Array via Time Tunnel, before I unflooded the Aruami Ruins. Since it was too hard for me, I teleported out because the stairs out were blocked by invisible walls.
If I ''had'' beaten the Array, would the walls have fallen and I could walk out instead of teleport out? Or is the intended way to exit before unflooding the ruins, always teleporting out?
